# jquery mobile submit vertical alignment issue

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have uploaded this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5p649ut/1/) to explain my issue. So, the problem is that the icon, or better, the submit input with icon, does not correctly align vertically with the text input... I have tried a lot of things but none of this works :(

The button in question is this:

```
<input type="submit" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-shadow="false" data-transition="slideup" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">
```

I'm using JQuery v.1.6.4 and JQuery Mobile v.1.0rc1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For whatever reason in the fiddle I can't select any elements in the form

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of JQM. Upgrade to 1.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you need to upgrade your version of jQuery mobile. 
If you can't, try this quick fix :

```
.ui-btn-inline {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It's a dirty way to do because the ui-btn-inline element is generated by JQM and you can't add a specific class to it...

Comment: Thank you! I was reading an out-of-date guide, that's the cause I was using their obsolete links. Now I have upgraded and all works fine, also the new default theme is beatiful :)